# How do i implement ChangeNotifier for a list for working with Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement Provider for my app and after doing some research i found that i have to implement ChangeNotifier for my Data class to update the UI when "days" changes.

I have seen people writing notifyListeners() in the setter method but always for a single property and never for a list. What is the correct implementation ?

Thanks !

This is my class and list :

```
class Data with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Day> days = [
    Day(
      name: 'Monday',
      transactions: [
        Transaction(
          isExpense: true,
          name: 'Pizza',
          transactionType: TransactionType.food,
          amount: '120€',
        ),
        Transaction(
          isExpense: true,
          name: 'EDEKA',
          transactionType: TransactionType.payment,
          amount: '120€',
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Day(
      name: 'Tuesday',
      transactions: [
        Transaction(
          isExpense: true,
          name: 'Sushi',
          transactionType: TransactionType.food,
          amount: '120€',
        ),
        Transaction(
          isExpense: true,
          name: 'Lidl',
          transactionType: TransactionType.payment,
          amount: '120€',
        ),
        Transaction(
          isExpense: false,
          name: 'Einkommen',
          transactionType: TransactionType.payment,
          amount: '120€',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Todo App is a good example deal with `List<Taks>` 
You can reference https://dev.to/shakib609/create-a-todos-app-with-flutter-and-provider-jdh 
full example github code https://github.com/shakib609/todos-flutter/tree/master/lib

code snippet

```
class Task {
  String title;
  bool completed;

  Task({@required this.title, this.completed = false});

  void toggleCompleted() {
    completed = !completed;
  }
}

class TodosModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Task> _tasks = [];

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get allTasks => UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);
  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get incompleteTasks =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_tasks.where((todo) => !todo.completed));
  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get completedTasks =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_tasks.where((todo) => todo.completed));

  void addTodo(Task task) {
    _tasks.add(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleTodo(Task task) {
    final taskIndex = _tasks.indexOf(task);
    _tasks[taskIndex].toggleCompleted();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteTodo(Task task) {
    _tasks.remove(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make 2 methods for adding and removing item.

```
void add(Day day) {
  days.add(day);
  notifyListeners();
}

void remove(int index) {
  days.removeAt(index);
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Thanks. So if  i wanted to edit a day, i would use both, right ?

Comment: yes, or if you can't get the index you could make a method with parameter Day day instead and do 'days.remove(day)'