# What does the query method do in Flutter Flame game and what type is it supposed to be?

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, flame

I'm trying to get the update function in Flame game to work.  I have a global variable called newInstructions that's a list that gets updated by a separate function.  I want the update function to check when there's a new addition to the list and call a function (populateInfo) with that list as input.  After looking at some of the documentation, I've come up with what I think would be the correct code, but it keeps returning this error:

> The method 'query' isn't defined by the type 'List'

I think that part of this might come from my not fully understanding what the update/query methods do.  With that, what does the query method do and what type should it be?  How would I go about changing my code to fix that error?

Here is the update function that I wrote:

```
  @override
  void update(double dt){
    final instructions = newInstructions.query<List>();
    populateInfo(instructions);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> With that, what does the query method do and what type should it be?

`query` is a Flame specific method that is used on the `OrderedSet` in each component where the `children` are stored, it is used to get children of a specific type. For example to get all `Player` components:

```dart
children.query<Player>();
```

> How would I go about changing my code to fix that error?

Since you want to react to when something is added the `newInstructions` list you shouldn't do this check in `update` since this method runs at least 60 times per seconds, it's better to just react once when there is a new instruction added.

This can be done in a few different ways, you could for example put the `newInstructions` list in a class that you then have an `add` method on that both adds the instruction to a list contained within the class, and also calls `populateInfo`. You could also wrap the list in a `ChangeNotifier` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218702/789545).