# How do you add an if statement to a TimerComponent in Flame Game Flutter?

Tags: flutter, timer, flame

I'm trying to add code to my Flame Game to check if a list isn't empty and if it isn't, then send it to a function.  However, I'm receiving an error on the if statement that says "Expected an identifier".  How do I change my code to run an if statement here?  Additionally, how would I cancel the Timer after it runs?

```
var instructions = [];
myGame(){
  add(
    TimerComponent(period: 2, repeat: true, onTick: () =>
      if(instructions != null){populateInfo(instructions)}),
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the query method do in Flutter Flame game and what type is it supposed to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527132/what-does-the-query-method-do-in-flutter-flame-game-and-what-type-is-it-supposed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use runtimeType, Use runtimeType to get the runtime type.
A property of the Object class, which is the base class of all objects in Dart, and of type Type.

```
 for (final element in gameRef.children) {
  if (element.runtimeType == Instructions) {
    //my element exist in the scene 
  }
}
```

I used the last code for explain the use of runtimeType, but with Dart you have more options like to

```
children.query<Intructions>();
```